# Query And Update Firebase Data From Comma Separated Value

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have below firebase database Structure where mobile_no is saved as comma separated value.Is it possible to query for individual mobile no from this comma separated value and later update or remove that inidividual no only separately.

[image]

Comment: it is not possible query individual mobile no. You will get full dMoble and then you have to separate each number using regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No its not possible to query each number alone, since if you query then you have to use something like this:

```
orderByChild("dMoble").equalTo(mobileNumbers)
```

`mobileNumbers` should contain all of those numbers for the query to work.

---

You need to seperate the mobile numbers for example:

```
randomID
    pLat   : pLat_value
    drp    : drp_value
    dMoble : dMoble_value 
randomID
    pLat   : pLat_value1
    drp    : drp_value1
    dMoble : dMoble_value1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can consider storing your data in [firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore) instead of [realtime database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database), firestore gives lot of flexibility of querying data also you can check if [number exists in array](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_and_array-contains-any), if you store above numbers in array, like this

```
CollectionReference driversRef = db.collection("drivers");

driversRef.whereArrayContainsAny("dMoble", Arrays.asList("181000001", "181000003"));//array of numbers that you want to search
```